# starting a storyboard from view model in wp8.1

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

i was working on mvvm architecture. i am trying to run animation made in blend from view model. i am able to make a story board object in my view model. but i am unable to use find method in order to find my story board name in view model class. tell me how to do it.

```
this is my viewmodel
class MypageViewModel :  INotifyPropertyChanged,IValueConverter
{

    private Visibility advancedFormat = Visibility.Collapsed;

    public  MypageViewModel()
    {
       // CheckedInCommand = new CheckInButtonClick();
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
       // unable to find 
        sb.Begin();
        advancedFormat = Visibility.Visible;


    }

}
```

////////// my story board in mypage.xaml

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="SecondaryGrid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-692.752"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Your ViewModel doesn't know about your View, therefore it cannot 'find' any elements. Perhaps you can use a `Trigger` to start the Storyboard when your `advancedFormat` variable changes. Although you'll first need to turn it into a property and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: yes i know . i have made the property etc in my project... but the issue is how can i get storyboard name so that i can run my animation.is there a way i can call any sort of event handler of a button or a tapped event in view model for a button or text in xaml page.